# Missing column data when using OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, outer-join, mariadb

Before I begin; this isn't your normal MySQL JOIN problem ... well as far as I can tell not a basic JOIN problem anyway.

Essentially my problem boils down to a query that I'm running which doesn't seem to return all the outer joined despite the data being present. The strange thing is that if I use an inner join the data is returned; also if I use a summary function (whilst using the outer join) the data is also returned.

We're running MariaDB :

> ```
> mysqld --version
> mysqld  Ver 10.0.12-MariaDB-1~wheezy-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (mariadb.org binary distribution)
> ```

I've been able to replicate the problem on a far simpler query which I will detail below (a simple ticket/transaction table and a customer/card table):

The tables look like this:

```
-------------------
|CUSTOMER         |
-------------------
|*card_number     |
-------------------

-------------------
|TICKET           |
-------------------
|*id              |
|card_number      |
|transaction_value|
-------------------
```

**The first query** is using the regular outer join which returns all sales (including non card sales). This is the data I'd like to receive, however if you look at the returned values, ticket id 8 does not have the card number attached (even though the count field indicates that it was found).

```
SELECT ticket.id,
       ticket.transaction_value,
       customer.card_number,
       COUNT(customer.card_number)
  FROM ticket
       LEFT OUTER JOIN customer ON ticket.card_number = customer.card_number
 WHERE DATE(ticket.timestamp) = "2014-11-09"
 GROUP BY ticket.id;
```

---

```
 id, transaction_value, card_number, count
 4 , 205.13           , {null}     , 0
 5 , 116.04           , xxx4785    , 1
 6 , 74.97            , xxx0281    , 1
 7 , 19.99            , xxx6836    , 1
 8 , 55.98            , {null}     , 1
 9 , 13.59            , {null}     , 0
```

**The second query** uses an inner join which only returns sales that have cards attached, however in this case we can see that ticket 8 now has a card number. Why did it not appear in the first query?

```
SELECT ticket.id,
       ticket.transaction_value,
       customer.card_number,
       COUNT(customer.card_number)
  FROM ticket
       JOIN customer ON ticket.card_number = customer.card_number
 WHERE DATE(ticket.timestamp) = "2014-11-09"
 GROUP BY ticket.id;
```

---

```
id, transaction_value, card_number, count
 5, 116.04           , xxx4785    , 1
 6, 74.97            , xxx0281    , 1
 7, 19.99            , xxx6836    , 1
 8, 55.98            , xxx0273    , 1
```

**Finally** I decided to try using a summary function: in this case I used the outer join again and found that ticket 8 has the card number attached again. I repeated with `MIN` and had the same result.

```
 SELECT ticket.id,
       ticket.transaction_value,
       MAX(customer.card_number),
       COUNT(customer.card_number)
  FROM ticket
       LEFT OUTER JOIN customer ON ticket.card_number = customer.card_number
 WHERE DATE(ticket.timestamp) = "2014-11-09"
 GROUP BY ticket.id;
```

---

```
 id, transaction_value, card_number, count
 4 , 205.13           , {null}     , 0
 5 , 116.04           , xxx4785    , 1
 6 , 74.97            , xxx0281    , 1
 7 , 19.99            , xxx6836    , 1
 8 , 55.98            , xxx0273    , 1
 9 , 13.59            , {null}     , 0
```

Can someone shed some light on what is going on here? I'd really like to be able to fix this problem without having to resort to complicated solutions like multiple queries or adding special summary functions etc. (i.e. things were fine with the outer join until this happened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I might have found the culprit; there is a bug in Maria 10.x which causes results to be omitted from outer joins when using group by: [MariaDB Bug Report](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-5719). Thanks to Aziz for making some good suggestions and helping me out. Hopefully this might help someone else who is as perplexed as I was!

**UPDATE: I have tested MariaDB 10.0.21 and can confirm the bug has been fixed.**

Comment: The bug has now been reported as fixed. I've yet to test it though.

Comment: I can now confirm the bug is fixed and tested.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a `GROUP BY` on `ticket.id`, however your `SELECT` list contains non-grouping columns too which are `ticket.transaction_value, customer.card_number`. This is causing data inconsistencies. Traditionally (in other RDBMS servers too) this would have generated a syntax error, however MySql allows it so the query writers have to make sure that they handle such situations themselves.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**

Comment: Thanks for offering some information. I'm going to give your link a read now. Just a side note: there is no data duplication; there is only 1 set of data to choose from, so not sure where it is getting the null from still.

Comment: Also, I quickly tried the same query without the count and group by. This resulted in the card details being returned which does seem to suggest it might be grouping related. Unfortunately for me it would be much better if I could get it working with the grouping as some of my queries rely on a set of summarised fields.

Comment: @Aaron based on my understanding I have tried to create a fiddle to reproduce this issue. Let me know if this covers your scenario: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f09e95/1

Comment: I've tweaked your fiddle to represent more how the data is stored and it seems to run fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0c10/1
You'll notice that the ticket ids cannot be duplicated + I'm using bigints to represent card numbers.
Its difficult for me to give out a data set (private customer information) and it seems that for small sets of data the problem does not occur. I can try generating some random data to see if I can produce a publicly available data set that will reproduce the problem.
At the moment I have approximately 5M rows in ticket and 600K rows in customer.

Comment: @Aaron if `ticket.id` is unique then why are you doing a `GROUP BY` on it?

Comment: In the final query (I've stripped out most of my other SQL to simplify the problem) there are multiple tables that are joined with summary functions on each which require a level of grouping. For example a customer may have 'pets' and I would like to include a COUNT on the customers pets in the query.

Comment: @Aaron sure it makes sense. I believe, grouping is the culprit here.